# Replance extension for shell script error

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write shell script (sh), Where I am getting below error

variable i contains:

```
 test.txt
```

code:

```
 echo "${i/.txt/}"
```

Error:

```
 just.sh: 16: just.sh: Bad substitution
```

expected output string :

```
 text
```

## Reproduce steps

Create file:

```
 touch text.txt
```

Create file test.sh contents using any of editor

code:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `find *.txt`
do
    echo "$i"
    echo "${i/.txt/}"
done
```

How to run:

```
 sh test.sh
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh` is not `bash`. Fix your shebang (the 1st line) as `#!/bin/bash` first.

References

- [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash), search "expansion" in the thread

  > Bash features a rich set of expanded non-standard parameter expansions such as `${substring:1:2}`, `${variable/pattern/replacement}`, case conversion, etc.